# What to know to start learning Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, education, mathematics

I am very interested in Quantum Mechanics, and I want to start learning some of the mathematics behind it - the simplification first, of course. What kind of mathematical ideas do I need to know and understand to follow along (e.g. Calculus, etc...). I'm sure that there is a huge list, but what are the main ones?

Comment: The list is actually not that huge. You should know calculus (up to and including vector calculus) and linear algebra. It can help to know some Fourier analysis, but it's not strictly necessarily. Same for basic probability theory.

Comment: have a look at the list here  https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-mathematical-background-required-to-study-quantum-mechanics

Comment: Thanks, I'll check all of that out :)

Comment: In line with the comment of @d_b, the QM texts I have used usually contain the main linear algebra components you need to do and understand QM. Although they do assume knowledge of calculus and vectors. Usually the probability is taught too, although at a really shallow level.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I assume you also need to know most A-Level maths concept too?

Comment: Can you get a copy of the three [*Feynman lectures*](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=feynman+lectures&gclid=Cj0KCQjw0brtBRDOARIsANMDykY8QqvmizAiz3nqXJRNwRi9pNUrzAwELx05xIKDHjrVdUZPFHb2nCYaAnJOEALw_wcB&hvadid=174259798921&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9002080&hvnetw=g&hvpos=1t1&hvqmt=e&hvrand=1016343955677957402&hvtargid=kwd-100492009&hydadcr=24659_9648993&tag=googhydr-20&ref=pd_sl_7yipyli092_e)? He starts by talking about the double-slit experiment, and I think that is by far the best intro to QM.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey You mean these?: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/

Comment: @Ironstone: Those should be good. Then if you need math, go learn it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!